# IMAP open stream: Self signed certificate issue

Tags: php, certificate, imap, self-signed, dovecot

I'm trying to open the non-secure (port 143) IMAP connection (I am using PHP):

```
imap_open('{localhost:143/imap}INBOX', USERNAME, PASS);
```

and I get the next error: `Certificate failure for localhost: self signed certificate ...`

Ok. I've tried to use `/novalidate-cert` mailbox param. Then I get another error: `Can not authenticate to IMAP server`.

I've also tried to combine all possible non-secure connection params like `/notls`,`/norsh` and `/secure`. But I always get errors.

This is the Dovecot configuration I'm using:

`* OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 LITERAL+ SASL-IR LOGIN-REFERRALS ID ENABLE IDLE STARTTLS AUTH=LOGIN] Dovecot ready.`

The certificate is really self-signed and generated with openssl.

The questions are:

1. Why does the certificate error occurs when I am using non-secure connection?
2. What is wrong with the mail server configuration?

Comment: Authentication error would point to your username and password being wrong.

Comment: @Max, yes, it's using STARTTLS, but how does it influence on the certificate?
Login and password are correct I suppose, I've copied them from the Mysql DB which is a storage for mail and accounts

Comment: STARTTLS of course uses the certificate to start the TLS channel, hence why you saw a self-signed cert error.  ``Can not authenticate``, however, implies your username and password are wrong.  Try logging in using telnet to verify your user and password are correct.

Comment: @Max, thx. The issue was really in the username and pass. But the error message was really confusing. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've upgraded my comment to an answer so you can accept it.

Comment: $this->conn = \imap_open( '{' . $this->server . '/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX', $this->user, $this->pass ) or die( 
    "Could not connect to imap server " . \imap_last_error() . PHP_EOL );

Answer (score 2, accepted):

STARTTLS of course uses the certificate to start the TLS channel, hence why you saw a self-signed cert error. `Can not authenticate`, however, implies your username and password are wrong. Try logging in using telnet to verify your user and password are correct

Answer (score 4):

Use this code

```
   imap_open('{localhost:143/imap/novalidate-cert/debug}INBOX', USERNAME, PASS);
```

Instead of this

```
    imap_open('{localhost:143/imap}INBOX', USERNAME, PASS);
```

Comment: Worked for me with `/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert`. The key here is use the `novalidate-cert` to inforce there's no request to validate the certificate against a know CA - Thanks for the tip. As Max says in his answer, the `Can not authenticate` is another story. As soon as I set the `novalidate-cert` I logged into the dovecot.